# React material ui textfield type number how to save decimal on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, material-ui

I'm working with this textfield:

```
const [qty, setQty] = useState({ qty: "0.00" });
.....
<TextField 
    required
    id="qty" 
    type="number"
    label="Qtà" 
    value={qty.qty} 
    step="1.00"
    variant="outlined" 
    error={HP_qty.length === 0 ? false : true}
    helperText={HP_qty}
    inputProps={{
      maxLength: 13,
      min: 0,
    }}
    onChange={onChange}/>
```

And onChange I update with this working statement:

```
setQty({ ...qty, [e.target.id]: e.target.value});
```

But on change a number for example from the default value "1.00" on clicking the up arrow it became "2".
Basically i lose the decimal that i want to keep. How could I save the decimal as well? The user has to be able to insert any numbers so for example: From 5,55 -> 6,8464 and with the arrow up the number is 7,8464.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are storing as a string, use `.toFixed` to format decimal places. This works with numbers only, so `(+e.target)` converts string to number.

```
setQty({ ...qty, [e.target.id]: (+e.target.value).toFixed(2) });
```

---

```
console.log((+"2").toFixed(2)) // "2.00"
```

---

```
console.log((+"5.6677").toFixed(2)) // "5.67"
```

Comment: but in this way the user could just put numbers with .00 at the end. I want that the user could be also able to put other numbers like 5,6677.  (1.00 is the start number, now with your solution i could only go on 2.00, 3.00 and so on...)

Comment: Nope, that is incorrect. See second example above. (English number locale)

Comment: hello Steve, if you could provide a jsfiddle it could be very kind of you because in my case your solution is not working. thank you

Comment: It's easy to test in any browser - just paste the console.log() as shown above, or substitute another string value to check something different.

Comment: I am confused about your use of decimal point. Initially you use `.` then you use `,`. Did you make a typo, or am I missing something?